# Changing to different views in swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am wanting to switch from a ".sks" to a ".storyboard" file within the app I am creating in swift 3, I have no knowledge of how to do this and I can't find any information that that tells me how.

Comment: It is not the same thing. you can't just take elements from .sks file and put them in a storyboard. If you are using UIKit, then you probably want to use storyboards. With SpriteKit, you may want to stick to .sks files.

Comment: is there no way to use a default button in sprite kit then or do i have to make all of my buttons?

Comment: I am just trying to put in an options page in my game

Comment: It is theoretically possible to use UIButton. Still, you are adding a button to the view, not to the scene in that case. So after every transition to next scene, you would have manually to add/remove those buttons. In SpriteKit we use SKSpriteNode (or its subclass) as buttons. There are many examples here how to do it. Or you can even search for third party buttons. And yeah, there is no buttons in SpriteKit framework at the moment of speaking.

Comment: so i just need to make a new scene?